# why the execution time of the first invocation of parallel stream is much bigger than the next ones

Tags: java-8, concurrency, parallel-processing, java-stream, execution-time

Here this method takes as arguments a function and a long. It applies the function 10 times on
the long passed to the method, registers the time taken by each execution in milliseconds, and
returns the duration of the fastest one.

```
   static long measure(Function<Long, Long> adder, long n) {
    long fastest = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        long start = System.nanoTime();
        long sum = adder.apply(n);
        long duration = (System.nanoTime() - start) / 1_000_000;
        System.out.println("duration: " + duration);
        if (duration < fastest) fastest = duration;
    }
    return fastest;
}
```

and i have this method  to sum the first n natural numbers:

```
 static long parallelSum(long n) {
    return LongStream.rangeClosed(1, n)
            .parallel()
            .reduce(Long::sum)
            .getAsLong();
}
```

when i invoked the measure method on n = 10_000_000

```
System.out.println("sum done in: "+ measure(Myclass::parallelSum, 10_000_000)+ " msec")
```

i get the following result:

```
duration: 64
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
duration: 2
sum done in 2 msec
```

my question is why always the duration of the first time the method `parallelSum` is invoked is much bigger than the next ones.

Comment: The JVM probably figured out how to optimize by the latter tests, and was still measuring the first time.

Comment: This is probably due to the Java JIT. You can run the whole computation multiple time in the same process to see if this is the root of the problem.